# Aurelia custom element without outer node

Tags: aurelia

Is it possible to let Aurelia render a custom element without the capsulating component node? Or replace the custom-element node with its content?

Example:

app.html

```
<template>
  <require from = "./components/custom-component.html"></require>
     <custom-component></custom-component>
</template>
```

app.ts

```
export class App {
}
```

custom-component.html

```
<template>
    <p>This is some text from dynamic component...</p>
</template>
```

Result

[image]

Based on this example: Is it possible with aurelia to render the `<p>` element from the component as direct child of the `<body>`, so that there will be no `custom-component`-node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `containerless` attribute on your component.

example: https://gist.run/?id=8e57000c7b8423dc0246a7006d90ba79

you can also decorate your custom components with the `containerless()` decorator.
see: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/9

Comment: Please note that the `containerless` attribute/decorator should only be used when absolutely necessary. It constrain some custom element functionality.